# Performant math operations on large Perl6 CArrays?

Tags: raku, nativecall

I have some large CArrays returned by a native sub that I need to perform basic element-wise math operations on. The CArrays are usually on the order of 10^6 elements. I have found that calling .list on them to them treat them as normal Perl6 types is very expensive. Is there a way to do performant element-wise operations on them while keeping them CArrays?

Short test script to time some methods I've tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
use v6.c;
use NativeCall;
use Terminal::Spinners;

my $list;
my $carray;
my $spinner = Spinner.new;

########## create data stuctures ##########

print "Creating 10e6 element List and CArray  ";
my $create = Promise.start: {
    $list = 42e0 xx 10e6;
    $carray = CArray[num32].new($list);
}
$spinner.await: $create;

########## time List subtractions ##########

my $time = now;
print "Substracting two 10e6 element Lists w/ hyper  ";
$spinner.await( Promise.start: {$list >>-<< $list} );
say "List hyper subtraction took: {now - $time} seconds";

$time = now;
print "Substracting two 10e6 element Lists w/ for loop  ";
my $diff = Promise.start: {
    for ^$list.elems {
        $list[$_] - $list[$_];
    }
}
$spinner.await: $diff;
say "List for loop subtraction took: {now - $time} seconds";

########## time CArray subtractions ##########

$time = now;
print "Substracting two 10e6 element CArrays w/ .list and hyper  ";
$spinner.await( Promise.start: {$carray.list >>-<< $carray.list} );
say "CArray .list and hyper subtraction took: {now - $time} seconds";

$time = now;
print "Substracting two 10e6 element CArrays w/ for loop  ";
$diff = Promise.start: {
    for ^$carray.elems {
        $carray[$_] - $carray[$_];
    }
}
$spinner.await: $diff;
say "CArray for loop subtraction took: {now - $time} seconds";
```

Output:

```
Creating 10e6 element List and CArray |
Substracting two 10e6 element Lists w/ hyper -
List hyper subtraction took: 26.1877042 seconds
Substracting two 10e6 element Lists w/ for loop -
List for loop subtraction took: 20.6394032 seconds
Substracting two 10e6 element CArrays w/ .list and hyper /
CArray .list and hyper subtraction took: 164.4888844 seconds
Substracting two 10e6 element CArrays w/ for loop |
CArray for loop subtraction took: 133.00560218 seconds
```

The for loop method seems fastest, but a CArray still took 6x longer to process than a List.

Any ideas?

Comment: One factor that makes the .list approach much slower than it needs to be is that it's first creating two lists with a Scalar + an Int (or maybe a NativeRef) for every slot in the CArray, which causes a ton of allocations and memory usage

Comment: i just pushed a commit to rakudo that makes `$foo[ ]` on CArray take less than ½ time.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you can work with a different native data type, Matrix and Vector, you can use the (also native) port of the [Gnu Scientific Library by Fernando Santagata](https://modules.raku.org/dist/Math::Libgsl::Matrix:cpan:FRITH). It's got a Vector.sub function you can use.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
use v6.c;
use NativeCall;
use Terminal::Spinners;
use Math::Libgsl::Vector;

my $list;
my $carray;
my $spinner = Spinner.new;

########## create data stuctures ##########

print "Creating 10e6 element List and CArray  ";
my $list1 = Math::Libgsl::Vector.new(size => 10e6.Int);
$list1.setall(42);
my $list2 = Math::Libgsl::Vector.new(size => 10e6.Int);
$list2.setall(33);

########## time List subtractions ##########

my $time = now;
print "Substracting two 10e6 element Lists w/ hyper  ";
$spinner.await( Promise.start: { $list1.sub( $list2)} );
say "GSL Vector subtraction took: {now - $time} seconds";
```

This takes:

```
GSL Vector subtraction took: 0.08243 seconds
```

Is that fast enough for ya? :-)

Comment: That looks like a pretty nice and performant module. I have long since solved this problem by just using C++ or Rust for these types of problems, but it is nice to see Raku getting modules like this.

Comment: Thanks to Frithnath, who's painstakingly creating wrappers for the whole library.